# Switching scenes with inputs

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Here's the code I know to change scenes with cocos2d:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorld scene]];
```

But I wonder if it's possible I can switch the scenes with some parameters.
I tried this method:

```
HelloWorld *scene = [HelloWorld scene];
[scene initWithInput:0];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
```

-(void)initWithInput:(int)input is what I wrote for test in HelloWorld class.

And it does't work, does any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the scene method. Something like

```
+(id) sceneWithInput:(int) i
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
HelloWorld *layer = [HelloWorld nodeWithInput:i];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];

// return the scene
return scene;
}
```

Then you would call
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorld sceneWithInput:0]];